# java mysql update statement error

Tags: java

i get the error message in the screenshot image i have added  when i try to update an existing field in the database what would be the problem

```
private void cmdUpdateMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {                                       
   String sql="UPDATE std set ADM_NO=?,Form=?,Student=?,Parent=?,Contact=?";


    try {
       ps=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
              ps.setString(1, txtadm.getText());
              ps.setString(2, txtform.getText());
              ps.setString(3, txtsname.getText());
               ps.setString(4, txtpname.getText());
              ps.setString(5, txtmobileno.getText());


          ps.executeUpdate();
```

[image: error screenshot]

Comment: What do you think the error means?

Comment: The error message is pretty self explanatory. You have another entry with the same primary key on your database.

Comment: `Duplicate entry 'sp13/21101/11' for key 'PRIMARY'`

Comment: how do i update data in the column without causing the  error

Comment: look at answers below

Comment: do some reading on basic

Answer (score 4):

You miss `WHERE` clause in your SQL, it updates whole table.
For update it generally requires primary key e.g. `WHERE primary_key_column=id`

Answer (score 0):

it looks that, you are trying to set a value to a field with is PRIMARY KEY what does mean that it could not have duplicated value, should be unique.

Comment: the same error occurs even when i change to a value that does not exist in the table

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your code is trying to update every row in that table:

```
UPDATE std set ADM_NO=?,Form=?,Student=?,Parent=?,Contact=?
```

You need to target the rows you want to update by using a where clause. I guess the ADM_NO is the primary key and the query is trying to update all rows to have the same primary key.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to update the primary key of the table to a value that already exists.

As you update without a `WHERE` clause this means you apply the update on all rows on the table and that does not work because you will set the primary key again and again to the same value.

Find out what is your primary key. Not sure what tool you use to administer the mySQL table but you could use

```
SHOW COLUMNS FROM std
```

I guess you primary key is `ADM_NO`

So you maybe need to code something like:

```
...
String sql="UPDATE std set Form=?,Student=?,Parent=?,Contact=? WHERE  ADM_NO=?";
...
          ps.setString(1, txtform.getText());
          ps.setString(2, txtsname.getText());
          ps.setString(3, txtpname.getText());
          ps.setString(4, txtmobileno.getText());
          ps.setString(5, txtadm.getText());
```

Just a guess

Answer (score -1):

Hello there is no "Where" clause this is too obvious there is a unique key on the file.